# In python 3, how can i transfer the data from a 2d array into a csv textfile

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, csv

This is my 2d list:

```
weapons = [['cannon','sword','bow','catapult','longbow','longsword','scythe','frying pan'],['bayonet','karambit','tommy gun']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Python's  CSV library has that power:*

```
import csv

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(weapons)
```